# How save product id of 1st item added to cart in woocommerce for a visitor in empty cart page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display the product id which is added to cart at first in empty cart page(`cart-empty.php`). Can anyone please help me with any solution.

Here is my code I have tried for `cart-totals.php` page..which save both product slug and its parent slug which is added at last to the cart.

```
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
            foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $item => $values) { 
                $_product = $values['data']->post; 
                $cartproductid = $_product->ID;
            }
            $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( $cartproductid, 'product_cat' );
            $url=$product_cats[0]->slug;
            $parenturl=$product_cats[0]->parent;

  $terms = get_the_terms($cartproductid, "product_cat");
  $cat = get_term_by("id", $parenturl, "product_cat");
  $newurl = $cat->slug;
```

Comment: Can you please make it clearer what you're trying to do. One important thing to note is that WordPress does not use `$_SESSION` so that will not return you anything.

Comment: I want the 1st product url that added to cart by the particular user. So that when one user empty the cart he can go to that product page

Comment: So you mean a popup or message, after the user selects to empty the cart that remembers the first product that was in the cart. Is this correct?

Comment: yes @ James Jones..Do you any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code displays a message whenever a user removes an item from their cart. It may not be exactly what you want but it gives you something to start off with. Add this code to your theme `functions.php` or custom plugin code:

```
function this_function( $title , $cart_item){
    wc_add_notice( 'Visit deleted product <a href="' . get_permalink( $cart_item['product_id'] ) . '">' . $title . '</a>' );

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed_title', 'this_function', 10, 2 );
```

**EDIT - More accurate solution**: This code displays a message on the empty cart page with a link to the last deleted product. It works for users who are logged in. If you want the code to work for non-logged in visitors you'll need to modify this to use cookies.

```
class empty_cart
{
    public $last_product;
    protected static $_instance = null;

    public static function instance() {
        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed_title', array($this, 'product_removed'), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty',  array($this, 'cart_is_empty'));
    }
    function product_removed( $title , $cart_item){
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'last_removed_product', $cart_item['product_id']);
        $this->last_product = $cart_item['product_id'];
        return $title;
    }
    function cart_is_empty(){
        $last_product = $this->get_last_product();
        echo 'Visit deleted product <a href="' . get_permalink( $last_product ) . '">' . get_the_title( $last_product ) . '</a>';
    }
    function get_last_product(){
        if( isset($this->last_product) )
            return $this->last_product;
        else
            return get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'last_removed_product',true );
    }
}

function empty_cart() {
    return empty_cart::instance();
}
empty_cart();
```

Comment: Thank ypu for your help..But, I want to place a button in the empty cart page which redirect the user to the last or first removed product archive page. Can you have the solution for this @James Jones?

Comment: @user3518270 I can take another look in 12 hours. Need to sleep now.

Comment: @user3518270 I have as improved solution in edited answer